# Reactjs+CRA+TS+Carco+Less don't correct work module system css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, less

I have problem with modules system css, for example that is my code files and configs:  react-app-env.d.ts, craco.config.js, CircleButtonWithMessage.module.less, CircleButtonWithMessage.tsx, discription below:

```
//react-app-env.d.ts
/* eslint-disable spaced-comment */
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
declare module '*.png'
declare module '*.jpg'
declare module '*.jpeg'
declare module '*.gif'
declare module '*.svg'
declare module '*.mp4'
declare module '*.mov'
declare module '*module.less'
```

```
//craco.config.js
const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less')
const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    { plugin: CracoLessPlugin },
    {
      plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          sourceMap: true,
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        },
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            orelativeUrls: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        source: 'tsconfig',
        baseUrl: '.',
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.path.json',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

```
//CircleButtonWithMessage.tsx
import React from 'react'
import ChatSvg from '@svg/chat.svg'
import BookIconSvg from '@svg//book_icon.svg'
import SkypeSvg from '@svg/skype.svg'
import cx from 'classnames'
import classes from './CircleButtonWithMessage.module.less'

const CircleButtonWithMessage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div
      className={cx(classes.navpanel__socials, classes.navpanel__socials_mg)}
    >
      <button type="button" className={cx('btn', classes.btn_mg)}>
        <img src={BookIconSvg} alt="" />
        <div className={classes.messages}>1</div>
      </button>
      <button type="button" className={cx('btn', classes.btn_mg)}>
        <img src={SkypeSvg} alt="" />
        <div className={classes.messages}>1</div>
      </button>
      <button type="button" className={cx('btn', classes.btn_mg)}>
        <img src={ChatSvg} alt="" />
        <div className={classes.messages}>1</div>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CircleButtonWithMessage
```

```
//CircleButtonWithMessage.module.less
@accent-color: #f23232;
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graphik LC Web';
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Medium-Web.ttf')
    format('truetype');
  font-style: normal;
}

.navpanel__socials_mg {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.navpanel__socials {
  .btn {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.messages {
  background-color: @accent-color;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Graphik LC Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 2px;
}
```

[image: I have next problem with module less]

here problem => import classes from './CircleButtonWithMessage.module.less' module.less don't work, webpack don't understand variables in less and simple selector, help me please(

**I won't eject my project and webpack manual configure, need resolve for use with carco**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I resolved that problem, next config:

```
    const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less')
    const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias')
    
    const lessModifyVars = {}
    module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        {
          plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
          options: {
            lessLoaderOptions: {
              lessOptions: {
                modifyVars: lessModifyVars,
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
          options: {
            lessLoaderOptions: {
              lessOptions: {
                modifyVars: lessModifyVars,
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
            modifyLessRule: function (lessRule, context) {
              lessRule.test = /\.module\.(less)$/
              lessRule.exclude = undefined
              return lessRule
            },
            cssLoaderOptions: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          plugin: CracoAlias,
          options: {
            source: 'tsconfig',
            baseUrl: '.',
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.path.json',
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```

that work for me, I need to describe callback modify Rule, but module less don't save selectors hierarchy inside, how can that I correct? for example btn selector doesn't will be to use(

```
    .navpanel__socials {
      .btn {
        position: relative;
      }
    }

...next code doesn't work normaly

 <button type="button" className={cx('btn', classes.btn_mg)}>
```

but I understood where I have problem, correct case below:

```
<button type="button" className={cx('btn', classes.btn, classes.btn_mg)}>
```